# Building an Lstm model and reshaping data

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, lstm-stateful

[Is scaling my data necessary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPbUX.png)

How can I make the input shape for my lstm model take 3dim and how do I get rid of the None value?

[For my input shape I am getting (?,100,100) I want it to be (473,100,100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovdUV.png)

[After importing my data X,Y.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqNo4.png)

[I split it into 3d shape to represent X=(n_samples,timestamps,features). Y remains unchanged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwD6N.png)

[Then I split and train my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTNoH.png)

[Then I scaled my data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPbUX.png)

[When modelling an lstm model i can only input the shape of (timestamp, feature) if i try make it (n_samples,timestamps,features) i get an error saying i gave 4dim instead of 3dim. With the shape (None, 473,100,100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjBeS.png)